# Angular and django unable to load ng-bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

I have a simple **angular file** that is **served by django**..Im unable to bind angular 
views.py

```
def home (request):
    return render(request,'index.html',{})
```

index.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>

        <div ng-app="">

            <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
            <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
            <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Though this is simple. my `ng-model="name"`  doesnot bind with `Hello {{name}}`

If I load my index.html seperatly as a **independent html file** it **works**, but **not with django**

Any help on this, why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because your html file is inside Django's scope. To deactivate Django's scope for a section of your html use `{% verbatim %}` and `{% endverbatim %}`:

```
{% verbatim %}
    <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
    <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
{% endverbatim %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just force angular to use different braces for denoting angular expressions.

```
.config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']}');
});
```

And your html code should be,

```
<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
<h1>Hello {[name]}</h1>
```

If you do like this, you don't need to add verbatim tag all the time to deactivate django's scope.